# Delta Query Using the Microsoft Graph SDK 1.4 NuGet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to set up a sample for delta query using the .NET client library (version 1.4 from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). Doing the initial calls is smooth:

```
var page = await _graphClient.Users.Delta().Request().GetAsync();

while (page.NextPageRequest != null)
{
  page = await page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

Getting the deltaLink after the while is still pretty obvious:

```
string deltaLink = (string)page.AdditionalData["@odata.deltaLink"];
```

But what is the correct way to later use this deltaLink? I haven't found the obvious method / builder that would allow me to continue at a later time by using the URL (my current solution is to use code from section "Send HTTP requests with the .Net Microsoft Graph client library" at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md and cast the thing to UserDeltaCollectionResponse - at that point I can use the normal APIs again).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct; currently, there is no elegant way to use the delta link as the basis for a new request. You will need to save it yourself and create a custom HTTP request:

```
HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, deltaLink);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
```

If you are looking to use it again within the same application instance, you can use it more easily:

```
driveItemDeltaCollectionPage.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, deltaLink.ToString());
driveItemDeltaCollectionPage = await driveItemDeltaCollectionPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
```

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/157) on this library to add more intuitive support for delta links.

Comment: One question, when data is returned using deltaLink, for removed items we get AdditionalData with @removed key; for new items, we simply get new items; how does it behave for edited/updated items ? any keys in AdditionalData ? or do we simply get the whole item (like for new items) ?

Comment: BTW, the referenced issue is now closed (and updated with the correct answer). It looks like an approach based on InitializeNextPageRequest() method can be used not only within the same application instance. All you should do is to create a new instance of DriveItemDeltaCollectionPage class.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote some code to get the actual delta token string.

```
 Uri deltaUri = new Uri(delta.AdditionalData[deltaLinkKey].ToString());
 var queries = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(deltaUri.Query);
 string token = queries.Get("$deltatoken");
```

There is then a QueryOption object in the API that you can add to the request. So, your code from above would look something like this.

```
QueryOption deltaOption = new QueryOption("$deltaToken", deltaToken);
var page = await _graphClient.Users.Delta().Request(new[] { deltaOption }).GetAsync();
```

Comment: I think this way is better then Caitlin's since you don't have to parse the JSON response yourself and can use the Microsoft.Graph user object...