# Microsoft graph - much of the user data returned from azure active directory is NULL

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am querying Azure Active Directory for users using Microsoft Graph API in .NET.
When i browse Active Directory in the azure portal, i can see the users have details such as user principal name.

When i query via .net however, the UPN is null (see image below)
This particular request was a delta query and the user is a new user.
The App Registration has the following Graph API permissions:
[image]

Any idea why the UPN is blank?

Code to get the delta:

```
        lastDeltaPage.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, deltaLink.ToString());
        usersPage = await lastDeltaPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);

        while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
            users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
        }

        if(usersPage.NextPageRequest == null)
        {
            usersPage.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out deltaLink);
        }

        return users;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set `.Header("Prefer","return=minimal")` ? I'm not sure if your issue related to this property, you may check [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#default-return-the-same-properties-as-initial-delta-request).

Answer (score 1):

Along with that please check the below points if they can help:

1. Sometimes when permission to read a certain type, members of that
   type are returned but with limited information. For the object types
   which the application does not have permission to read only the the
   object type and ID are returned.

Please see [**Use delta query to track changes in Microsoft Graph data - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview)
[image]

1. Also there might not be any changes or updates to the user , or the properties are set to null so
   [**changes may return null**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20requests,to%20null%20value.)

Also check [Delta Query Using the Microsoft Graph SDK 1.4 NuGet - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193116/delta-query-using-the-microsoft-graph-sdk-1-4-nuget)

**References:**

1. [limited-information-returned-for-inaccessible-member-objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#limited-information-returned-for-inaccessible-member-objects)
2. [user: delta - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
3. [Delta Queries In Microsoft Graph API Using C# – TekExpo
   (wordpress.com)](https://tekexpo.wordpress.com/2020/09/25/delta-queries-in-microsoft-graph-api-using-c/)

Comment: hi Yes, the issue turned out to be different. I was using a delta link that was not selecting the values. as the values are encoded in the delta link url, it wasnt obvious that not all columns were selected.